# Query on DbSet calls password setter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 web application with a DbSet of Users. The Context initializer seeds some sample users in the database with the password "password". The following setter is called in User:

```
private string _password;
public string Password {
    get { return _password; }

    set {
        //Password checks here
        _password = Crypto.HashPassword(value);
    }
}
```

The password gets hashed fine.
In the Login action of the AccountController, I first grab the User from the database and then I check if the correct password was entered:

```
User u = repos.FindBy(model.Email);
if (ModelState.IsValid && g != null && u.IsPasswordCorrect(model.Password)) {
```

FindBy does this:

```
return users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.Equals(email))
```

The user is found just fine, but I found out by debugging that this query to the DbSet calls the Password setter of the user with the hashed password as value??? So the password gets hashed TWICE... First when I seed the sample users with password "password", and second when this query calls it with the already hashed value. This is why the IsPasswordCorrect fails and I can't login. :-(

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592675.aspx) the DbContext calls the setter to initialize the DbSets, but why does this get called when I query it? Making it a private setter doesn't help.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming that `users` in the FindBy method is the DbSet. Given that, and this is just a guess, but when EF retrieves the data from the database it needs to get it from the underlying result set and put it into the object. It seems reasonable that it would use the property setters to initialize the newly-created object. So when you say `users.FirstOrDefault` it retrieves the data from the database, including the hashed password, creates a new `User` object and runs through the property setters to initialize it.

Comment: Yes, `users` is the DbSet, sorry for the confusion. That's the problem, but I have no idea how to solve it in a clean way... I can check the password length and if it equals that of a hash, don't hash it, but that's not nice... I can't check if `_password` equals the given `value` (the hash), 'cause `_password` is lost (`null`) upon the initializion of a new `User` object by the `DbSet`

Comment: You need a function to Hash the password and should not do it in the property. what I mean is use `Password = Crypto.HashPassword(yourpassword)`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't think this is the cleanest solution (as I have a double setter now essentially), but it works fine at least :-)

```
public string Password { get; set; }
public void SetPassword(string password) {
    //Password checks
    Password = Crypto.HashPassword(password);
}
```

Comment: How could you say its not cleanest solution? The entity you are using is POCO entity(just a guess). Hashing the password is not the job of the password property, but is the job of the object in which it is contained. Password property should not do any smart work of hashing anything that comes in. It is the job of the container object to make proper decision about what has to be done with all the members.